Pip failed with status code 1. Use --debug for more information
According to this document of Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-cli?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=public I want to add ml extension by az extension add -n ml. However, I get this error:
An error occurred. Pip failed with status code 1. Use --debug for more information.```

extra info:
  "azure-cli": "2.61.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.61.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.1.0",
  "extensions": {}


Check if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1455242/azure-cli-error-when-add-extensions-an-error-occur

Have already uninstalled Anaconda Navigator. Still doesn't work.
